# mat-checkbox that display the error TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I work on an angular application. In a component, I have the following code

```
export class GlobalComponent {
  @Input()
  form!: FormGroup<DeepRequired<GlobalBean>>
```

with the following template extract

```
..................
<mode-impression-ticket [form]="form" [labelCheckBox]="text" ></mode-impression-ticket>
...................
```

Here is the following mode-impression-ticket component

```
@Component({
  selector: "mode-impression-ticket",
.............
export class LocalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  form!: FormGroup<DeepRequired<GlobalBean>>

  localForm: FormGroup<DeepRequired<GlobalBean>> | undefined;



@Input()
  labelCheckBox!: string

  ngOnInit() {
    this.localForm = Object.assign({}, this.form);
    console.log(this.localForm);
    console.log(this.localForm.controls['flag']?.value);
    console.log(this.labelCheckBox);
```

The objective of the preceeding component is to get the values of fields with the same form and afterwards forward it to its parent
The console.log above don't give any error and print value

With the following template extract

```
@Component({
  selector: "mode-impression-ticket",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="localForm">
    <mat-checkbox  formControlName="flag">{{labelCheckBox}}</mat-checkbox>
.........................................
```

And there is an error at line <mat-checkbox  formControlName.........

```
TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
```

### UPDATE

this.form is initialized in two component above (grand parent component in a method which is the following underneath). The child, parent and grand parent component have the same form

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = VtForm.build(this._route,
      FormHelpers.getInitData(this._route),
    )
  }
```

Comment: Where is the init from `this.form`?

Comment: see the update above

Answer (score 0):

I forgot also to tell you that I use @ng-stack/forms

Finally I use the same form as parent and don't duplicate it

```
export class LocalComponent {


  @Input()
  formGroup!: FormGroup<Required<VtParamTermIhmBean>>
```

Furthermore, I changed the template (see the following post: [reactiveform that does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972296/reactiveform-that-does-not-compile)) and everything was put in order. The discussion is closed. Thank you